# What does the suffix -mentum add to a word's meaning?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, derivation, suffixes

Lewis and Short lists [275 words ending in *-mentum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=mentum&lang=la), many of which have come into English:

- argumentum
- augmentum
- documentum
- fragmentum
- pigmentum
- segmentum
- etc.

Wiktionary (cited as an example, not as an authority) says that it is:

> derived from the Latin suffix -menta in collective nouns like armenta (“herd, flock”). Latin -menta from Proto-Indo-European *-mn̥teh₂ (*-mn̥ + *-teh₂).

This confuses me because "collective nouns" hardly seems to describe the majority of these words. I know almost nothing about PIE, so the root words above don't help illuminate the meaning for me.

One pet theory that occurred to me is that perhaps there is a relationship between -mentum and the Greek middle/passive participle ending: -μενον (-menon). It's far-fetched, but works in at least a few cases, e.g. *argumentum = quod arguitur, fragmentum = quod frangitur, documentum = quod docetur, etc.*
(Disclaimer: words selectively chosen to support my theory.)

Can anyone provide an overview of **what kinds of words generally use the -mentum suffix**, and also comment on **whether it adds a predictable meaning to its root word**?

Comment: My understanding was something like "result of ____", somewhat similar to -menon.

Comment: To add somewhat to what Draconis has said, my understanding has always been that -mentum shows either instrument (by which the verb that serves as the root is done) or the results of activity (denoted by root). Instrument: a pigmentum is used for painting (pingo), an argumentum is used for proving something (arguo), etc. Result: a fragmentum is the result of breaking (frango), etc.

Comment: All those you've chosen take **-atio** which intuitively would be the *contrasting* abstract form: fraction, in-doctrination,

Comment: WIktionary's statement makes no sense to me. Weiss (2011:313-4) says "*-mentum* looks like the neuter substantivization of a possessive derivative in *-to-* derived from neuters in *-men*", adducing parallels in Indo-Iranian and Germanic.

Comment: On the suggested relationship with Gk. -μενος, it's not impossible, but would have to be posited at a "deep" stage of (pre-)PIE, since both the suffixes (*-men* [n.] and *-meno-*) already existed in PIE. There are some Latin forms which have been proposed as possibly cognate with -μενος, though: *alu-mnus*, *fē-mina*, and the 2pl. pass. ending *-minī*.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but it is interesting that many of the words in *-mentum* have a mostly synonymous counterpart in *-men*, e. g. *fragmen-fragmentum, docimen-documentum*. Looks like both these forms coexisted in many cases I just looked up; for one, per L&S, *doci/umen* was being used by Ter and Lucr and documentum by Cic.

Comment: @TKR: I would second that there is probably no close (Latin timeframe) connection with the middle participle PIE ending and our *-men/-mentum*. For one, Beekes believes *femina* and *alumnus* are the only two surviving Latin examples of (lexicalized) PIE middle participle.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Miller (2006: 76, 78), the endings *-men* and *-mentum* form a deverbal (with one exception) noun with the semantics of **means, instrument** or **result** of action of the verb. Relevant quotations are

> **§3.4 *-men* [...] ‘means, instrument, result’**
>   While *-men* is formally and functionally related to *-mentum* (LG i.§326), the
>   latter will be treated separately for reasons stated in §3.5. [...] Of the two, *-men* has ceased to be productive since its main function was taken over by *-mentum*. Most *-men* derivatives have full grade of the root, but a few have zero grade as well; see *-mentum* below and Schumacher (2000: 114 f.).
>
> **§3.5 *-men-tum* [...] ‘means, instrument, result’**
>   Historically, *-mentum* is sometimes considered an enlargement of *-men* of
>   Indo-European date (LG i.§371). As mentioned in §3.4, numerous doublets
>   existed, such as *reg-i-men/reg-i-mentum* ‘rule’. Syntactically, however, *-mentum* shares more with Greek *-μα-/-ματ*, from <PIE> *-mn̥-*(*-mn̥-t-*)
>   (IEL 209), than with L<atin> *-men* (Sandoz 1994: 328). Apart from rare deadjectivals, such as rudimentum [...] (<from> *rudis* [...]’), most of the examples are deverbal.

To summarize and provide exact answers to the questions, the ending (I would rather not call it the suffix) *-mentum*

1. mostly used to transform verbs, and a few specific adjectives
2. into a noun capturing the semantic category of either *instrument* or *result* of the verb's action.

---

Speaking of your “pet theory,” I would not call it incorrect right off the bat. While it does not align *morphologically* with the state of PIE affairs in Latin, it has its merit: your examples *quod arguitur, quod frangitur, quod docetur* are essentially periphrases for the (missing) middle participle. Then, *semantically* the Latin paradigm *quod X* is close enough in its semantics to that of instrument or result of action. This is not so much a straightforward theory, but rather a way of roughly delineating the semantics of the ending *-mentum*. The *quod* construct is fuzzier, however: Is *quod pingitur* something being dyed (more of the passive sense), or something being applied as a dye (more of the middle sense)? *Pigmentum* is the instrument, an aligns more with the middle sense of the *quod* construction, while *quod pingitur* out of context would be less specific.

---

It is also notable that the doublets that Miller is speaking about (*fragmen-fragmentum, documen-documentum*, perhaps no less than 100 of these) are not observed of "older" nouns, continuously traced back to the proto-language (such as *nomen, germen, semen, stamen, vimen, omen*)—there is no e. g. **nomentum*. This is a clear illustration of the fact that the ending *-mentum* was productive in Latin, while *-men* was not, and many of the *-men* words were probably back formations from their *-mentum* counterparts.

---

**References:**

Miller, Gary D (2006) Latin Suffixal Derivatives in English and their Indo-European Ancestry. Oxford
LG = Manu Leumann et. al. (1977) Lateinische Grammatik, Munich: Beck.
IEL = Meier-Brugger (2003) Indo-European Linguistics, Walter de Gruyter.